# Compile error when installing native gem for eventmachine -v '0.12.10'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundler, eventmachine

I'm having trouble to setup a project with `rake bundle_install`:

```
$ rake bundle_install
cd nats && bundle install
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (5): [cd nats && bundle install...]

Tasks: TOP => bundle_install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using daemons (1.1.8) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
checking for main() in -lcrypto... no
creating Makefile

make
compiling sigs.cpp
compiling cplusplus.cpp
compiling files.cpp
compiling kb.cpp
kb.cpp: In member function â€˜virtual void KeyboardDescriptor::Read()â€™:
kb.cpp:79:27: warning: ignoring return value of â€˜ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)â€™, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  read (GetSocket(), &c, 1);
                       ^
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp: In function â€˜VALUE t_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)â€™:
rubymain.cpp:468:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function â€˜VALUE t_bind_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)â€™:
rubymain.cpp:488:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/heavenize/.bundler/tmp/15236/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/heavenize/.bundler/tmp/15236/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then when I try the required version of `eventmachine` I got the follwing output:

```
$  sudo gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... yes
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for epoll_create() in sys/epoll.h... yes
checking for main() in -lcrypto... no
creating Makefile

make
compiling sigs.cpp
compiling cplusplus.cpp
compiling files.cpp
compiling kb.cpp
kb.cpp: In member function â€˜virtual void KeyboardDescriptor::Read()â€™:
kb.cpp:79:27: warning: ignoring return value of â€˜ssize_t read(int, void*, size_t)â€™, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
  read (GetSocket(), &c, 1);
                           ^
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp: In function â€˜VALUE t_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)â€™:
rubymain.cpp:468:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
rubymain.cpp: In function â€˜VALUE t_bind_connect_server(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)â€™:
rubymain.cpp:488:42: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   rb_raise (EM_eConnectionError, e.what());
                                          ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [rubymain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

I've the following setup:

```
$ rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: why are you using such an old version of the gem?

Comment: The reason is that at the end of the output from `rake bundle_install`, it asks to try `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` before trying to setup the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen it seems there is an issue with this version, the only way I found to solve this issue  was this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/_mRzGCd7DdQ). My suggestion is look in the Gemfile.lock and see which gem requires that version and think about if you actually need it or check if that gem is update because that is a really old version of eventmachine.

Comment: I manged to fix the issue by following this [article](http://fhanik.blogspot.fr/2013/11/installing-ruby-193-on-ubuntu-1204.html), and it was a ruby version problem. I endup installing `ruby1.9.3p551` with `rvm`.